# Services 32bit dlls on 64bit machine

Tags: dll, service, 64-bit, 32-bit

I've built and installed my service from vs2010 onto a 64bit machine.

My problem comes in when my service references 32 bit dlls (spssio32.dll to be precise) - I get the error in my event viewer : **"System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"**

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Regards,
Byron Cobb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your service code written in a .NET language?  If so, you need to mark it as targeting `x86` rather than `Any CPU` (via Project properties / Build / Platform target).

(By default, .NET code targets `Any CPU`, meaning that on 64-bit machines it will compile into x64 machine code.  Because such 64-bit code can't load 32-bit DLLs, that can lead to failures like the one you're seeing.  Where code has a dependency on a 32-bit DLL, it needs to always compile to 32-bit machine code even on 64-bit machines, hence setting the target platform to `x86`.)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with my build mode in release set to x86.

Comment: Ah - My Solution was set to compile as any CPU and even though I had the build in x86 it was using the solution properties. It works now - Thanks, you're a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a COM surrogate

http://www.dnjonline.com/article.aspx?id=jun07_access3264

The other variant is to spawn an external 32 Bit server-process and add a .NET remoting interface to it and your 64 bit application, so you can use .NET remoting for interprocess communication.